# Why doesn't my MongoDB $or query work?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to perform an "$or" search to match of of two regular expressions as follows:

```
{
    "metadata.text": {
        "$or": [
            {
                "$regex": ".*hello.*"
            },
            {
                "$regex": ".*world.*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using mlab.com and am receiving the following error:

```
MongoDB error: "Command failed with error 2: 'unknown operator: $or' on server ZZZZZZZ. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $or", "code" : 2, "codeName" : "BadValue" }." Please contact support@mlab.com if you need assistance.
```

Why is $or detected as an unknown operator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Unknown operator: $or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48530123/mongodb-unknown-operator-or)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply because $or should be a top level operator in your query, like this:

```
db.collection.find({
        "$or": [
            {
                "metadata.text": { "$regex": ".*hello.*" }
            },
            {
                "metadata.text": { "$regex": ".*world.*" }
            }
        ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the `$or` statement doesn't apply to a single field, but rather must have the field specified for each item:

```json
{
  "$or": [
    {"metadata.text": {"$regex": ".*hello.*"}},
    {"metadata.text": {"$regex": ".*world.*"}}
  ]
}
```

### Explanation

Per [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), the `$or` syntax is as follows:

> ```javascript
> { $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
> ```

Note that unlike a lot of operators, it does not include a field name.  For instance, contrast [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), which does include the field name:

> ```javascript
> { field: { $exists: <boolean> } }
> ```

In other words, rather than:

```json
{
  "metadata.text": {
    "$or": [
      {"$regex": ".*hello.*"},
      {"$regex": ".*world.*"}
    ]
  }
}
```

you need:

```json
{
  "$or": [
    {"metadata.text": {"$regex": ".*hello.*"}},
    {"metadata.text": {"$regex": ".*world.*"}}
  ]
}
```