# MongoDB: Unknown operator: $or

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to do a simple or query for mongoDB, but I do get the error **MongoError: unknown operator: $or**

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
const query = {
  title: { $exists: true },
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
}

// ...do some stuff
// now need to change category query...

query.category = {
  $or: [
    { $exists: false },
    { $eq: [] }
  ]
}

// should return documents with missing category field or empty array value
Content.find(query)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my MongoDB $or query work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014849/why-doesnt-my-mongodb-or-query-work)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is that the `$or` statement doesn't apply to a single field, but rather must have the field specified for each item:

```javascript
$or: [
  {category: {$exists: false}},
  {category: {$eq: []}}
]
```

### Explanation

Per [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), the `$or` syntax is as follows:

> ```javascript
> { $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
> ```

Note that unlike a lot of operators, it does not include a field name.  For instance, contrast [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), which does include the field name:

> ```javascript
> { field: { $exists: <boolean> } }
> ```

In other words, rather than:

```javascript
{
  title: { $exists: true },
  category: {
    $or: [
      {$exists: false},
      {$eq: []}
    ]
  }
}
```

you need:

```javascript
{
  title: { $exists: true },
  $or: [
    {category: {$exists: false}},
    {category: {$eq: []}}
  ]
}
```

### Question's example

Putting it all together with your exact example, you end up with:

```javascript
const query = {
  title: { $exists: true },
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
}

// ...do some stuff
// now need to change category query...

delete query.category
query.$or = [
  {category: {$exists: false}},
  {category: {$eq: []}}
]

// should return documents with missing category field or empty array value
Content.find(query)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
query = {
  $or: [
    {
      category: { $exists: false }
    },
    {
      category:[]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -6):

I don't have a convenient way to test for you, but try adding quotes like this:

```
query.category = {
  "$or": [
     { "$exists": false },
     { "$eq": [] }
  ]
}
```